# How to use display to print which module this module is binding from?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm writing a system verilog code.

and I try to print some info of binding file.

I have an assert coverage that will make an error in a specific situation.
I want to print out which binding file is the problem when the error occurs.
Is there any way to print that info from binded module?

for example

file 1

```
bind A1 main(.sour(a), dest(b));
bind B1 main(.sour(c), dest(d));
```

file2

```
module main(
input a,
input b
);
assert_unknown: assert property(a)

else begin
    $display(XXXX) // how to print the info that is error from A1 or B1?
end
```

how to print the info that is error from A1 or B1?

I tried to use %m to print hier, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$error` instead of `$display`. That will print the scope and location of the assertion.

BTW, `%m` should have worked to print the scope. It would help if you explained what *not working* really means.